# Find the most efficient JVM serialization performance metrics

Tags: java, serialization, jvm, deserialization

Hello all i find a GitHub repository
https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki
that has analyzed the performance of different JVM serializations methods. My problem now is that i am trying to understand which has the best performance. For example in the figure above the lowest ser+des times is considered the best time
or the highest is the best? Please help me and if possible explain to me to understand better how to read metrics?
[image]

Comment: To be 100% sure you understand what those benchmarks mean, read the source code.  But, my reading is that the numbers in the first 4 columns are nanoseconds, and smallest means fastest.  Compare each table with the bar charts above them.  This confirms the units.

Comment: I am not going to use the word "best" because that is a value judgement (i.e. non-objective) ... unless the "goodness" criteria / measures are clearly stated.  Fastest is not necessarily best.  There are many criteria to consider.